# ajax JSON success always fire while error=>true

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i don't understand, each time success is fired while the return of my controller is {error=>'true'}. Here is my JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: root_url + 'getInfo/' + idClient,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                for (var x = 0; x < data.retour.length; x++) {
                    content += data.retour[x].startdate;
                    if(data.retour[x].aconfirmer == 1)
                        content += '&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-warning" title="À confirmer"></i>';
                    content += "<br>";
                }
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        });
```

And here is my controller:

```
function getInfo($idClient)
{

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    try
    {
        if($info= $this->infos->getInfos($idPatient))
        {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'retour' => $info));                
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
            //return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true', 'Message'=>$e->getMessage()));
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my Inspector i can see the return there it is:
{"error":"true"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already catching the error in your code, and returning a regular response with {error:true}. 
The thing is the request is successful and returns 200 OK, so it fires the success function, to be able to invoke the error function, the http request has to completely fail, 500, 404, etc... .

To do what you want, you have to do one of the following:

- 1) Not catch the error
- 2) Through error status code your self
- 3) Handle this into success function and check if the error flag is
  true in the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the best option, knowing that in the futur i would like to log errors?

Comment: @Alexking2005 That's just programming style opinion, there's no best answer.

Comment: @Barmar is right ...  My personal style is to check success like you are .. And then through a series of checks (IN THE SUCCESS) check for the error and return false at that point.

Comment: Barmer is right, its a style opinion, but myself, I prefer as you do now so that the server errors could be easily distinguished from regular http request errors.
@Alexking2005

Comment: I just replaced echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true')); by this: echo http_response_code(400); but this: error: function(e){
                    console.log( e.responseText);
                } returned '200', is that normal?